# Lyx Paragraph Settings not working

Tags: spacing, lyx, indentation, paragraphs

I keep unchecking the indentation box in the lyx paragraph settings, but after I apply the change, and go back to my work, it never seems to work. I will then write a new line, and press enter and it automatically indents the next line.

When this happens, I go back to the paragraph settings only to see the indentation box is checked.

This happens for all of the paragraphs settings, not just the indentation. For instance, I also tried to change the justification and the line spacing, but it never seems to work when I apply the changes.

Is there a way to fix this bug, or should I just uninstall lyx and try to download it again?

Answer (score 3):

When you right click in a paragraph and choose *paragraph settings*, those settings apply *only to that paragraph*. To make global changes, go to Document --> Settings --> Text layout.